# Clique-Width of the Complement of a Cycle

Tags: graph-theory

I have been asked to show, as an exercise, "that the clique-width of the complement of a cycle is at most $5$". However if we define $C_{n}$ to be the chordless $n$-cycle with $V({C_{n}}) = \{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}$ and $E({C_{n}})=\{v_{1}v_{2},v_{2}v_{3},...,v_{n}v_{1}\}$, the following seems (to me at least) to be a valid $4$-expression for $\overline{C_{n}}$:

$\eta_{4,2}(4(v_{n})\oplus...\oplus(\rho_{4\rightarrow3}(\rho_{3\rightarrow2}(\eta_{4,2}(\eta_{4,1}(4(v_{5})\oplus\rho_{4\rightarrow3}(\rho_{3\rightarrow2}(\eta_{4,2}(\eta_{4,1}(4(v_{4})\oplus(\eta_{3,1}(3(v_{3})\oplus(2(v_{2})\oplus1(v_{1})))))))))))))...)$

If this is correct, then we have shown a stronger result than the exercise asks for. Am I missing something or is it a strange exercise?

Many thanks.